# Software RAID unmount before shutdown

Tags: linux, centos, software-raid

I have my mysql directory */var/lib/mysql* mounted in */dev/md0*.
When I shutdown/reboot my server, the system fails to switch the md0 in read-only mode because devices are busy, obviously by mysql.

During the startup, it causes some delay because of error scan and the drives are not mounted before the system try to reassemble the RAID array and mount it.

I need to **service mysqld stop, umount /dev/md0, then mdadm --stop /dev/md0**, so the server will shutdown cleanly and restart without any problems.

Is it the standard procedure when there's a software raid or the system should have been able to do it by itself ? Is there a way to do those steps automatically before a shutdown/reboot ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

The init system should shut down mysqld. Do you have a `/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K*mysqld` and  `/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K*mysqld`? Did you install mysql-server from an RPM?

Comment: Yes I have K*mysqld in both location, and I have install mysql-server with RPM (5.1.56 on a CentOS 5.5). I don't know if the problem is mysqld not stopping or the /dev/md0 that isn't umount.

Comment: You could try manually stopping mysql and then reboot. If /dev/md0 gets unmounted cleanly then it is mysql and you need to try to determine why mysql isn't shutting down properly.